# wordpress: modfiy the blog entry

Tags: wordpress, loops, genesis

I want to show video in the blog entry in the home page...   (tzahirozental . co . il)
for some reason its ignor the video in the post and show only the text in the blog entry.
I know there some filter that I need to change in the loops.php but I dont know what.

```
function genesis_legacy_loop() {

global $loop_counter;

$loop_counter = 0;

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    do_action( 'genesis_before_post' );

    printf( '<div class="%s">', join( ' ', get_post_class() ) );

        do_action( 'genesis_before_post_title' );
        do_action( 'genesis_post_title' );
        do_action( 'genesis_after_post_title' );

        do_action( 'genesis_before_post_content' );
        echo '<div class="entry-content">';
            do_action( 'genesis_post_content' );
        echo '</div>'; //* end .entry-content
        do_action( 'genesis_after_post_content' );

    echo '</div>'; //* end .entry

    do_action( 'genesis_after_post' );
    $loop_counter++;

endwhile; //* end of one post
    do_action( 'genesis_after_endwhile' );

else : //* if no posts exist
    do_action( 'genesis_loop_else' );
endif; //* end loop
```

}

thanks alot.

*the theme working on Genesis Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the video coming from? from the content of a post? I think you should search your files for `genesis_post_content` and see where this action hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the below code to your theme's `functions.php` file to add post formats to your site.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
    'aside',
    'audio',
    'chat',
    'gallery',
    'image',
    'link',
    'quote',
    'status',
    'video'
) );
```

Also include the following to add post format images.

```
add_theme_support( 'genesis-post-format-images' );
```